# Azure Functions: NodeJS - HTTP Response Renders as XML Rather than HTTP Response

Tags: node.js, xml, azure, response, azure-functions

I have an Azure function written in NodeJS where I'm attempting to cause an HTTP Redirect with a 302. The documentation is very sparse on what are valid entries in the response. As a result I've created an object with what I feel should be the correct entries to generate the redirect, but all I get is an XML response. Even items like the status code are shown in the XML rather than changing the real status code.

What am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
module.exports = function(context, req){
    var url = "https://www.google.com";
    context.res =  {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
            Location: url
        }
    }
    context.done();
}
```

This is the response I'm getting in the browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 1164
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2017 00:54:20 GMT
Connection: close

<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><KeyValueOfstringanyType><Key>status</Key><Value xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d3p1:int">302</Value></KeyValueOfstringanyType><KeyValueOfstringanyType><Key>headers</Key><Value i:type="ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType"><KeyValueOfstringanyType><Key>Location</Key><Value xmlns:d5p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d5p1:string">https://www.google.com</Value></KeyValueOfstringanyType></Value></KeyValueOfstringanyType></ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're not defining the "body" in the response. This can be set to null, but it must be set for Azure functions to interpret it properly.

e.g. Update your code to:

```
module.exports = function(context, req){
    var url = "https://www.google.com";
    context.res =  {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
            Location: url
        },
        body : {}
    }
    context.done();
}
```

You will then get the desired response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Expires: -1
Location: https://www.google.com
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2017 01:10:13 GMT
Connection: close
```

---

Edited 2/16/2017 - Using "null" for the body currently throws an error on Azure. As a result the answer was updated to use {} instead.

Comment: I don't see the null body error. If you're still hitting it it, can you post the error message?

Comment: Full repo code found here:
https://github.com/securityvoid/azure-bug/tree/master/app-function-test

See this as well:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1208#issuecomment-282164915

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with azure functions, see this [content headers issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1268).

For now, a workaround is to remove any content related headers if the body of your response is null.